# Free Real-Time Currency conversion Exchange Rate xml feed url

Tags: iphone, ios5, xml-parsing

Any link offering the real-time updating xml data feed to integrate in iphone app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try these xml files

http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html

http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml

Comment: other than the above links are also appreciated !!

Comment: FYI themoneyconverter.com feeds has been discontinued.

Answer (score 5):

you can try yahoo , its free

> For example, to convert from GBP to EUR: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv

which give data in .csv file which easily can be parsed.

Comment: Doesn't work today.