# Using string to change into array but the string is details extracted from Oanda.com

Tags: javascript, php, regex, arrays, explode

I was trying to get the currency rate from Oanda.com . because the exchange rate is really standard compared to Yahoo. Api .

So now I am able to get the details which is in some kind of string . I wanted to separate them and use the exact currency rate i want lik USD/CSR .

```
<?php
    $code=file_get_contents('http://www.oanda.com/embedded/converter/show/b2FuZGFlY2N1c2VyLy9vYW5kYV9ob21lX3BhZ2U=/0/en/');    
    $tmp=explode('<script type="text/javascript">var rates =',$code);
    $tmp=explode('</script>',$tmp[1]);
    $array=trim($tmp[0]);
    var_dump($array);
    $array1 =explode('pairs',$array);
    var_dump($array1[0]);
    var_dump($array1[1]);
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393173/free-real-time-currency-conversion-exchange-rate-xml-feed-url) question.

Comment: So you want `0.73141` as your output ?

Comment: Well I solved it it retiurns Json array so I used json_decode() for it and it worked :) . Sorry for not replying earlier

Comment: Guys have a look at my class which is totally working fine as of now with my website integration it can be used with any number of website you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!defined("PLUGIN_CONVERSOR_PHP")){

define("PLUGIN_CONVERSOR_PHP",1);
class plugin_conversor{
    var $parent;/*class parent (plugin.class.php)*/
    var $conversion_rates;
    function plugin_conversor($parent){ /*constructor*/
        $this->parent=$parent;
        $this->conversion_rates=array();
    }


    public function getYear($pdate) {
        $date_array=explode('-', $pdate);
        return $date_array[0];
    }

    public function getMonth($pdate) {
        $date_array=explode('-', $pdate);
        return $date_array[1];
    }

    public function getDay($pdate) {
        $date_array=explode('-', $pdate);
        return $date_array[2];
    }

    public function createTodayRatesFile(){/*Create the rates file for today*/
        ini_set('display_errors','on'); 
        $info = serialize($this->conversion_rates);
        $path = $this->parent->parent->config->pathPlugins.'conversor/info/'.date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/'.date('d').'/';
        $file = $this->parent->parent->config->geo.'.php';
        if(!file_exists($path))
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        file_put_contents($path.$file,$info);   
        ob_start();
        system('chmod 777 '.$file);
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    public function checkRatesFile($date){/* Check the file of an specific date */
        ini_set('display_errors','on'); 
        $info=array();
        $path= $this->parent->parent->config->pathPlugins.'conversor/info/'.$this->getYear($date).'/'.$this->getMonth($date).'/'.$this->getDay($date).'/';
        $file=$this->parent->parent->config->geo.'.php';
        if(file_exists($path.$file))
            $info=unserialize(file_get_contents($path.$file));

        //print_r($info);
        return $info;

    }

    public function fetchCur(){ /*Get the conversion rates for all the foreign currencies from oanda*/
        $code=file_get_contents('http://www.oanda.com/embedded/converter/show/b2FuZGFlY2N1c2VyLy9vYW5kYV9ob21lX3BhZ2U=/0/en/');
        $tmp=explode('<script type="text/javascript">var rates =',$code);
        $tmp=explode('</script>',$tmp[1]);
        $array=trim($tmp[0]);
        $array1 = json_decode($array, true);
        $cur = $this->parent->parent->config->conversionCurrencies;
        $rates_array = array();
        $myArray = $array1['pairs'];
        //print_r($myArray);
        $myaskRate = $array1['askRates'];
        $mybidRate = $array1['bidRates'];
        foreach($cur as $key=>$val){
            $cur_key= array_search($val,$myArray); /* get the key for the current currency*/
            $rates_array[$key] = round(($myaskRate[$cur_key]+$mybidRate[$cur_key])/2,2);
        }

        $this->conversion_rates = $rates_array;
        $this->createTodayRatesFile();
        echo "<br>"; /*we store in the conversion_rates attribute all the conversion rates for the foreign currencies of the site*/
    }

    public function UpdateDB(){
        $this->fetchCur();  
    /*check the conversion rates for yesterday*/
        $yesterday = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y")));
        $yesterday_rates = $this->checkRatesFile($yesterday);

        $sql=array();
        $sqlii=array();
        /*pcurrency1 will be used for the price in national currency always. And pcurrency2, 3, etc will be used for the price in the foreign currencies*/

        /*First we fill pcurrency1 for all the properties that are in national currency*/
        $sql[]= 'UPDATE propiedades '.
                'SET Pcurrency1=Palquiler '.
                ' WHERE Idmoneda='.$this->parent->parent->config->nationalCurrency.' AND Palquiler>0;';

        $sql[]= 'UPDATE propiedades '.
                'SET Pcurrency1=Pventa '.
                ' WHERE Idmoneda='.$this->parent->parent->config->nationalCurrency.' AND Pventa>0;';

        $set_clause=array();
        $search_array = array_diff($yesterday_rates,$this->conversion_rates);
        foreach($this->parent->parent->config->currenciesField as $id_currency=>$field_name){

        /*For each foreign currency we fill the value in the corresponding field*/
            if(array_key_exists($id_currency, $search_array))

            {

            $sql[]= 'UPDATE propiedades '.
                    'SET '.$field_name.'=Palquiler, '.
                    'Pcurrency1=Palquiler*'.$this->conversion_rates[$id_currency].
                    ' WHERE Idmoneda='.$id_currency.' AND Palquiler>0;';

            $sql[]= 'UPDATE propiedades '.
                    'SET '.$field_name.'=Pventa, '.
                    'Pcurrency1=Pventa*'.$this->conversion_rates[$id_currency].
                    ' WHERE Idmoneda='.$id_currency.' AND Pventa>0;';   

        /*Walk the foreign currencies array of the site*/   
           $sqlii[]='UPDATE propiedades SET '.$field_name.' = Pcurrency1/'.$this->conversion_rates[$id_currency].' WHERE '.$field_name.' IS NULL OR '.$field_name.' <= 0; ';

            $set_clause[]=$field_name.' = 0';
        }}  
        /*execute the queries*/
        $query = array_merge($sql,$sqlii);
        $set_string=implode(' , ',$set_clause);
        $sql_query='UPDATE propiedades SET Pcurrency1=0 ';  
        if(count($set_clause)>0)
            $sql_query.=', '.$set_string;
        $sql_query.=';';

        echo 'Running... '.$sql_query.'<br>';
        $this->parent->parent->database->query($sql_query);         
        for($i=0; $i<count($query); $i++){
            echo 'Running... '.$query[$i].'<br>';
            $this->parent->parent->database->query($query[$i]);   
        }   
}

}
    }
?>
```